# Помогите грамотно построить фразу по-русски

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Начата* отправка гранулы в отдел расфасовки или *начато*?

(Я работаю в газохимическом заводе.)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что низкокачественный.

Comment: Одной гранулы? *Начата отправка гранул в отдел расфасовки* и *Я работаю НА газохимическом заводе*.

Answer (score 3):

"**Отправка**" - существительное женского рода. Поэтому правильно: "**начата отправка**".